# bulding desktop apps with air and C#

Tags: c#, air

how can I build a C# app with air interface??
I want to ask about using the very impressive interface of adobe air and implement the code with C#.
here I want to use adobe air instead of windows forms or WPF.

Comment: Next time do more research on what .net offers already. Silverlight is much more convenient than AIR in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have a look at Silverlight, its a good Microsoft alternative to Adobe AIR. Especially if you're already familiar with C# and WPF.

..also as far as I know, Adobe AIR can only wrap applications built using Html/Javascript, Flash or Flex